# How to add all jars contained in a folder to hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

How to add all of the jars contained in a folder to hive?
I know you can add multiple jars using
`ADD JARS <filepath1> [<filepath2>]*` 
But it becomes very inefficient for too many jars. So, is there any other method to add the jars contained in a folder?

Comment: Adding the jar folder to HADOOP_CLASSPATH might help

Comment: This works but i am not looking for this solution. I want to know the trick for adding jars directly through script or command line.

Comment: check the answer. Is this what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add directly through a script. Here is one of the simple trick.

Hive Script

```
ADD JARS :CUSTOM-JARS
-- Hive code
CREATE SCHEMA ...
CREATE TABLE ...
```

Invoking this from command-line or script

```
$ hive -hiveconf CUSTOM_JARS="/<path-to-jar-folder>/*.jar" -f hive-script.hql
```

This will replace `:CUSTOM_JARS` with all the jar file names during execution.

Comment: Getting this error `Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: :CUSTOM_JARS` while executing the script.

Comment: This worked for me. I think there is a problem in how you are referring to your jars. . can you provide the command executed and the jars location details

Comment: I followed the exact the instructions but still getting the same error. So, now i am using .hiverc to add jars.

Comment: Are you using absolute path or relative path for jar location?

Comment: I am using absolute path.

Comment: not sure what went wrong for you. Try to execute from the jars directory. i.e just use `$ hive -hiveconf CUSTOM_JARS="*.jar" -f hive-script.hql`

Answer (score 0):

In order to add it permanently recommended ways are as follows.

1. add in hive-site.xml

   `<property>
   <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
   <value>file://localpath/yourjar.jar</value>
   </property>`
2. Copy and paste the JAR file to the `${HIVE_HOME}/auxlib/` folder